# Asynchronous Shield UI JavaScript Chart creation and data binding

Tags: javascript, shieldui

After having tried a couple of ways to solve the issue, I decided to ask for some help. The thing is, that I provide information on a website, which users in most cases don’t look too much. On the other hand this information needs to be a click away if needed. So I am using a Shield UI JavaScript chart, that binds to remote data. What I need is to initialize the chart, but not to show the data. This needs to be postponed until (and if) the user clicks on the chart.
Is there a way to bind the data later (asynchronously). How can this be achieved?
Below is some code I worked on, for testing purposes it is local data.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>

<meta charset="utf-8" />

 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../../css/shieldchart.css" />

<script src="../../../../external/jquery-1.8.2.min.js" type="text/javascript">//</script>
<script src="../../../../external/jquery.mousewheel/jquery.mousewheel.js" type="text/javascript">//</script>
<script src="../../../../external/canvg-1.2/rgbcolor.js" type="text/javascript">//</script>
<script src="../../../../external/canvg-1.2/canvg.js" type="text/javascript">//</script>
<script src="../../../../external/globalize/globalize.js" type="text/javascript">//</script>

<script src="../../../../common/core.js" type="text/javascript">//</script>

<script src="../../../js/shieldchart.js" type="text/javascript">//</script>

</head>
<body>

<div id="container" style="width: 600px; height: 400px; margin: auto;"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        var Information= [12,22,22,12,32,44,34 ];      


        $("#container").shieldChart({
        events: {
            seriesClick: function pointSelectHandler(args) {
        var containterproducts = $("#container").swidget();
        containterproducts.destroy();
        $("#container").shieldChart({

            exportOptions:
                  {
                      image: false,
                      print: false
                  },          
            primaryHeader: {
                text: "Electricity prices"
            },

            dataSeries: [
                {
                    seriesType: 'pie',
                    collectionAlias: "User Information",
                    data: Information
                },
            ]
        });                    
            }
        },
            exportOptions:
                  {
                      image: false,
                      print: false
                  },          
            primaryHeader: {
                text: "Click to show data"
            },

        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You are on a right way to solve the problem. You initially create a chart that contains no data and eventually bind it to the data source.
However you may not use the seriesClick event, since you don’t have any series that the user can click on.
If you want to use that event, than you need to add for instance a single value, let’s say 1, so that the user is able to click on the pie:

```
dataSeries: [
   {
      seriesType: 'pie',
      collectionAlias: "Logins",
         data: [1]
   },
]
```

or alternatively, you can have your code and only change the event used:

```
click: function pointSelectHandler(args) {}
```

In this case you will show the data when the user clicks on the chart and won’t be in need of any series.

This is the more comfortable strategy, because with the pie chart type it is easy to visualize a sample data series. But if you are using line type chart it will be more complicated for the user to get to know that he needs to click on a data series to get the actual data.